# Disable highlighting of active cell in DashTable

Tags: plotly-dash

How can I stop the active cell (the cell clicked on last) being highlighted  in a dash datatable?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be achieved by inheriting the background color and border when the cell is selected using conditional styling when creating the data table:

```py
style_data_conditional=[
    {
        "if": {"state": "selected"},
        "backgroundColor": "inherit !important",
        "border": "inherit !important",
    }
]
```

---

Alternatively, you should be able to achieve this by adding a custom CSS file into the assets folder of your project. How to do this is explained in [the Dash forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/remove-or-change-hotpink-selection-from-datatable/26168/4).

I have completely removed the highlighting by setting values to transparent.

```html
.dash-spreadsheet-container .dash-spreadsheet-inner table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-family: monospace;
        --accent: transparent  !important;
        --border: transparent !important;
        --text-color: transparent !important;
        --hover: transparent !important;
        --background-color-ellipses: transparent !important;
        --faded-text: transparent !important;
        --faded-text-header: transparent !important;
        --selected-background: transparent !important;
        --faded-dropdown: transparent !important;
        --muted: transparent !important;
    }
```

Comment: unfortunate no solution

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking online for an hour or so to find this...

Comment: confirmed the style_data_conditional approach. thanks!

Comment: The `style_data_conditional` example above works great AND it means you can switch colors/themes and not having to hard code any colors

Answer (score 6):

Actually is really much simpler (at least in Python Dash DataTable). You can use the DataTable attribute `cell_selectable=False`. Docs [here](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference).

```
from dash import dash_table
dash_table.DataTable(
                      id="datatable-interactivity",
                      columns=columns,
                      data=data,
                      cell_selectable=False,
                     )
```

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while and none of the solutions i found online worked.

The 'hotpink' selection can be styled by putting a .css file, i.e. datatable.css into the assets folder.

The content of my file is:

```
td.dash-cell.cell--selected.focused {
  background-color: #c4f0d5 !important;
}

td.dash-cell {
  border-color: #d8d8d8 !important;
}
```

where the first style is for the highlighted/focused cell and the second is styling all cells in the table, here the border color.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also note you can simplify the css rule with ".cell--selected" which ensure every selected cells will be affected (not only the active one but all if there is a multiselection from the user)